# How can I get the amount of carts in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Is it possible to get the total of carts created on my ecommerce in Google Analytics?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get it from the metric Products Adds to Cart:

[image]

Or i GA4:

[image]

Comment: Great! How did you add these both column Products Adds to Cart and Product Checkout on Product Performance page?